# install forked repo's dependencies correclty

Tags: github, npm

I forked a repo in [here](https://github.com/tiny-byte/telegram-node-bot). then I installed it by `npm i --save tiny-byte/telegram-node-bot`. which installed it correctly, but dependencies of the repo is not installed!

I had to manually browse into **node_modules** folder in my project and hit `npm i` to install dependencies. It's working ok on my local machine but I think something is missing.

What should I do on production server to install all dependencies correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not related to your fork it's about `prepublish` script in https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot/blob/master/package.json#L8

You need to run `prepublish` script after install or make an issue to main repo and ask them to solve it

For temporary solution you can run `npm run prepublish` into node_modules/tiny-byte/telegram-node-bot or add it to `postinstall` script.